# How to get sub-content from wikipedia page using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, wikipedia

I am trying to scrape sub-content from Wikipedia pages based on the internal link using python, The problem is that scrape all content from the page, how can scrape just internal link paragraph, Thanks in advance

```
base_link='https://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AA%D9%87%D8%A7%D8%A8_%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%82%D8%B5%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%AA'
sub_link="#الأسباب"
total=base_link+sub_link
r=requests.get(total)
soup = bs(r.text, 'html.parser')          
results=soup.find('p')           
print(results)
```

Comment: Could you please check your total variable which use `base_link` twice. Also the `sublink` should be `sub_link`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because it's not a sublink you are trying to **scrape**. It's an anchor.

Try to request the entire page and then to find the given id.

Something like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import requests

base_link='https://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AA%D9%87%D8%A7%D8%A8_%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%82%D8%B5%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%AA'
anchor_id="ﺍﻸﺴﺑﺎﺑ"
r=requests.get(base_link)
page = soup(r.text, 'html.parser')
span = page.find('span', {'id': anchor_id})
results = span.parent.find_next_siblings('p')
print(results[0].text)
```

Comment: Thank you very much